# Spring Tool Suite Eclipse is not able to deploy correctly Java EE web project when using resources folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Using jar as packaging, Spring Boot requires that xhtml templates be putted in the src/main/resources/META-INF/resources right?
But when I start the project using Right Click -> Debug as -> Spring Boot App I have an error says me template is not found

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Dec 28 11:21:09 BRST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/fichadeespera/login.jsp
```

When I build the project using cmd command "mvn clean package" and start it with "java -jar artifact.jar" there is no problem, it starts and shows pages correctly.

Comment: @BalusC this occurs only with JSF. Using freemarker I had no problem.

Comment: JSF can't do anything to this STS problem.

Comment: Fine. Using Netbeans, there is no problem to deploy. Seems like it only occurs with the Eclipse Spring Tool Suite.

Comment: It's that STS thing, not Eclipse itself.